can we decrypt a hash function of SHA256
if i have a  hash SHA-256 , i want to decrypt it i know that result is in the format of string of length 40 which contains both small and large alphabet and 0-9 number (randomly)
which method i have to adopt

Are you aware that hash value do not contain the input data? A hash function maps the input data to a number, in this case 256 bits wide. SHA was invented to make finding data with the same hash value most difficult. What did your own web research reveal, and why did it not help you? What is the underlying actual problem you try to solve?

Hash functions do not encrypt data but produce a "fingerprint" of the input with three conditions:

you can't find two different inputs that produces the same output
you can't find a second input for a given input that produces the same output
you can't find the input to a given output

To find the input for the given hash you need to try every possible input and check if the chosen input results in the given hash.
If you want to know more about that take a look at the book "A Graduate Course in Applied Cryptography" by Dan Boneh and Victor Shoup chapter 8.1.
Also the hash length doesn't sounds right. It should be 256 bit long

If the input is longer than the hash, there need to be multiple different inputs resulting in the same output. However, finding them is deliberately most costly.

Do you mean finding collisions ?

Yes, concerning your first condition. And given enough time and calculation power, the second condition is wrong, especially with short hashes.

these three points are the properties of a secure cryptographic hash function. collision resistance, second pre-image resistance and pre-image resistance
